# Retrieving Django QuerySet matching field in reverse query (related_name)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I apologize for the title... it's really hard to explain my question in one line.

I'm trying to determine a way to retrieve all objects of one model that match a field in another model through an objects related_name set.

Examples of my models:

```
class InvDetail(models.Model):
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey('SalesOrder', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=TRUE)
    [...]other invoice related fields[...]

class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    [...]a bunch of sales order specific fields[...]

class SOSeller(models.Model):
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey('SalesOrder', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salesperson = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I'm trying to get is all of InvDetail objects that are linked to SalesOrder objects that has a SOSeller object that is linked to a particular UserProfile object.

In my case, an individual sales order can have multiple salesperson attached to it (in which case, they all get credit for commission purposes, for example)

Right now, I am iterating through a for loop of all the InvDetails, (or really, filtered down to a particular date range, which I didn't show in my model).

```
invdetails = InvDetail.objects.all()

filtered_inds = []

for invdetail in invdetails:
    sellers = invdetail.sales_order.soseller_set.all().values_list('salesperson__user__username', flat=True)

    if name in sellers:
        filtered_inds.append(invdetail)
```

This gets me a list of all of the invoices associated with a particular salesperson, but it is painfully slow, especially as the number of invoices that it has to iterate goes up.

I've been trying to think of a better way to query for the data, maybe through Q or F functions, but I've been unable to figure out a way to get the same data with them...

Something like

```
inv_details = InvDetail.objects.filter(sales_order__soseller_set__contains='tom')
```

Originally my models were set up so that I just had a ForeignKey field linked to one salesperson per sales order, and that was easy to gather all the invoices that a salesperson was associated with, but I was requested to be able to add other salesperson so that multiple salespeople could be associated with any particular sale...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was near the right answer, when you create the filter based on related models you should not use the `set` postfix, for example, for the models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    pass

class InvDetail(models.Model):
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey('SalesOrder', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class SOSeller(models.Model):
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey('SalesOrder', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salesperson = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

query will be:

```
InvDetail.objects.filter(
    sales_order__soseller__salesperson__username__contains='tom'
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  As an aside, I actually had set up a related_name on my SOSeller model, so for anybody coming in here looking for a similar solution, in Bear Brown's query above, use the related_name instead of the model name (i.e. I had "so_sellers" as my related name, so my query was .filter(sales_order__so_sellers__salesperson__username__contains='tom')

Comment: good! you can edit my answer to add your solution, and if it help you, you should accept the answer for other who will search the same issue.